# Divergence for this integral.

Tags: real-analysis

What's a way to show that the integral
$\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{px^2}d x$
diverges for $p \ge 0$ and converges for $p <0$, where $p$ is a real number.
Now for $p=0$ it's pretty straightforwards, but since the integrand can't be integrated in the conventional sense, how do I show for the case of p>0 and p<0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have: If $p > 0$, $\displaystyle \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{px^2}dx = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{px^2}dx = 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty e^{px^2}dx > 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty px^2dx =2p\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty x^2dx = \infty$.

If $p < 0$, then $2\displaystyle \int_{0}^\infty e^{px^2}dx = 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{e^{qx^2}}dx < 2\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{1+qx^2}dx$ converges since $q = -p > 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$p>0$: The integrand fails to go to $0$ as $|x|\to\infty$. Such a continuous function is never integrable over $\mathbb{R}$.

$p<0$: Prove the claim for $p=-1$ (this is a standard exercise), then in the general case integrate by substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the integrand function is even, we only need a bound for the integral over $\mathbb{R}^+$. If $p<0$ then:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{px^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}e^{px^2}\,dx + \int_{1}^{+\infty}e^{px^2}\,dx \leq 1+\int_{1}^{+\infty}e^{px}\,dx\leq 1-\frac{1}{p}.$$
If $p>0$, then the integrand function is greater than $e^p$ for any $x\geq 1$.